# Mono could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource'

Tags: .net, linux, mono

I'm trying to start a Windows console application under Linux using monodevelop. Everything compiles just fine and in general looks OK but then the following exception is thrown:

System.Configuration.ConfigurationException: Unrecognized element 'performanceCounters'.

I'm not sure if I am missing a reference or if this is something that just doesn't work under mono.

Comment: Which Mono version are you using? EventSource was added fairly recently. The 4.0 assembly version is expected, as 4.5 is an in-place update for 4.0 and has the same version number.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that the version number was actually correct. I'm running Mono Develop 4.0.12

Comment: I was asking for the **Mono** version, not MonoDevelop :) Run "mono --version" on the command line. Anything earlier than 3.6 is likely not going to work.

Comment: oops, sorry... Yeah, it is 3.2.8, I'll bump it and see if that sorts my problems

Comment: So I built mono 3.8 from source and still have the same problem. But I do think it is quite possible that I have rubbish files on my PC after I went through some dependency hell

Comment: You don't need to build 3.8 from source, binary packages are available: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ If you make a small program that reproduces the problem and post it as a gist/pastebin I can try it here.

Comment: I updated the question as the problem is starting to seem a lot let mono related and a lot more environment related

Comment: Problem solved... I purged all the mono packages and then installed mono 3.8 and monodevelop 5.0.1 from source. Now everything is working as expected.

Comment: I take that back, now there is a new problem with the configuration

Comment: Can you share the program or config that raises this? Do you have a 'performanceCounters' entry in your app.config?

Comment: This is the config <performanceCounters filemappingsize="1048576" /> It is a transient dependency introduced by one of the compiled packages which I don't have the code for. What it does seems straight forward enough and works perfectly under Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<performanceCounters />` element in the System.Diagnostics app.config section is currently not processed on Mono, so it raises an exception. I sent a [pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1287) to fix this.

Note that the value set by the element isn't used in Mono, so it has no effect.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much

Comment: @Leon: I suspect it wasn't caught until now cause [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229387(v=vs.110).aspx) actively discourages setting it in app.config: "If you define the size in your application configuration file, that size is only used if your application is the first application that causes the performance counters to execute. Therefore the correct location to specify the filemappingsize value is the Machine.config file"